# Почему каждый аргумент в maven начинается с -D

Tags: maven

```
-DgroupId...
-DartifactId...
-DarchetypeArifactId...
-DinteractiveMode...
...
```

каждый аргумент начинается с "D", почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все предельно просто. `-D` - `Define a system property`, а все дальше - это собсвтенно само свойство (пропертис). А так как в большинстве случаев однобуквенные параметры от значения не нужно разделять пробелом, оно так и получается. То есть, на самом деле maven видит так параметры

```
-D groupId... -D artifactId... -D archetypeArifactId... -D interactiveMode
```

А у maven есть ещё много-много других [параметров](http://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/command-line.html).